# UIWebView Zoom Issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview

How can we identify that a user has zoomed the webView so as to resize the other components present. My webView starts from the middle of the screen and when a user zooms the webView it starts to scroll horizontally and vertically but it happens within the webView.The scrolling happens internally. I want to lock the webView from scrolling internally so that when a user scrolls vertically, the labels,textfields etc. on top of the webView also scroll up and not the webView alone. What I want to achieve is pretty similar to iPhone Native Email Client. For accomplishing this, I would like to put this webView on top of a scrollView and when a user zooms it, I would like to reset the content size of my scrollView so that whatever is added to the scrollView like labels and textfields above the webView also scroll when I scroll the webView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

- Disallow user to pinch zoom the webview
- Detect double tap on your scrollview and toggle webview's scalesPageToFit property AND set userInteractionDisabled on webview

Now you can scroll only scrollview which has all the controls..

Comment: The user should be allowed to pinch zoom or if scalesPageToFit compresses the content of the webView, then how will users view it.

Comment: as i mentioned, you can detect double tap and toggle the webview's scalesPageToFit property.

Answer (score 0):

You can find help from this

[Disabling default zoom effect](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/)
and 
[scalesPageToFit property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950)